# Golang AWS SAM lambda Function debugging is not working on M1 Mac

Tags: apple-m1, aws-sam, goland

When trying to debug simple SAM, I'm receiving the following error:

```
could not launch process: fork/exec /var/task/hello: function not implemented
```

Is anyone knows how to solve it?

The full log is:

```
Mounting /Users/.../HelloWorld as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
START RequestId: 87012bed-214a-4603-8f3c-675ce1551167 Version: $LATEST
API server listening at: [::]:60198
2022-01-18T17:21:55Z warning layer=rpc Listening for remote connections (connections are not authenticated nor encrypted)
2022-01-18T17:21:55Z info layer=debugger launching process with args: [/var/task/hello]
could not launch process: fork/exec /var/task/hello: function not implemented
2022/01/18 17:21:55 exit status 1
18 Jan 2022 17:21:55,118 [ERROR] (rapid) Init failed error=Runtime exited with error: exit status 1 InvokeID=
API server listening at: [::]:60198
2022-01-18T17:21:55Z warning layer=rpc Listening for remote connections (connections are not authenticated nor encrypted)
2022-01-18T17:21:55Z info layer=debugger launching process with args: [/var/task/hello]
could not launch process: fork/exec /var/task/hello: function not implemented
2022/01/18 17:21:55 exit status 1
END RequestId: 473c16f3-4562-40aa-9a9f-1528fe87aaaa
REPORT RequestId: 473c16f3-4562-40aa-9a9f-1528fe87aaaa  Init Duration: 1.18 ms  Duration: 1041.97 ms    Billed Duration: 1042 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 128 MB
```

Comment: Please see: https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-jetbrains/issues/2983#issuecomment-980490429

Comment: @s0xzwasd already tried.. didn't work